# How to make custom emacs keybinding print text in the buffer?

Tags: emacs

I want the keybinding `C-;` to print `console.log();` and then go back two characters so as to place the cursor in the middle of the parentheses. This is what I have coded:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-;") 'print-command)

(defun print-command ()
  (interactive)
  "console.log();"
  (backward-char)
  (backward-char)
  )
```

Upon execution, the cursor does go back two characters, but `console.log();` isn't printed. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You insert text into the buffer with `insert`.

```
(defun insert-console-log ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "console.log();")
  (backward-char 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to record a macro, save it and use that.

```
M-x kmacro-start-macro
```

type console.log();  remembering to record your two back characters

```
M-x kmacro-end-macro
M-x name-last-kbd-macro  insert-console-log
M-x insert-kbd-macro insert-console-log
```

You can then paste the output into your initialisation file (with your shortcut definition):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-;") 'print-command)
(fset 'print-command
   [?c ?o ?n ?s ?o ?l ?e ?. ?l ?o ?g ?\( ?\) ?\; left left])
```

This has the obvious disadvantage that editing your "function" becomes trickier!